# Is it possible to pass model to Laravel's action and automatically instatiate it with matching post data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

It would be perfect if this is possible to set type hint for Controller's action to an existing model and this way force action to instatiate the model with data passed by post method (if post fields match the model fields ). I know this from asp.net MVC and it works perfect but couldn't find the way to do something similiar in Laravel.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean route-model binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you set `$fillable` property on `User` model it could be done in they way like this:

```
class UserService
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->user = User::create(request()->all());
    } 

    public function getUser()
    {
       return $this->user;
    }

}


class UserController
{
    public function store(UserService $service)
    {
       $user = $service->getUser();
       return redirect()->route('users.show', $user);
    }
}
```

but this is rather non-standard behaviour. I don't see any need to create models automatically like this, much reasonable would be putting into controller just:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

What you should also consider is the fields that should be filled in, the most reasonable is to pass directly which fields should be used for example like this:

```
$user = User::create($request->only('name','email','password'));
```

Comment: Very good answer! It looks really convenient and makes solution to my need in just one line of code. The solution with generating service is pretty neat also. Thank you, unfortunately I can' test this out right now so I will accept the answer when I can :)